# If $\int f=0$ then $f=0$ a.e. using Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

I am really stuck on the last bit, but also want to know if my solutions is correct, there may be others out there but I fully understand my own solutions and would like proof verification I guess. And every step I take I want to know if I gave the correct reason why, I am very picky about understanding fully every step of my solutions.

Let $f$ be a function. Assume $f$ is integrable and non-negative on some Lebesgue measurable set $E$. Here measure is given by $m$. For $\alpha>0$ define
$$E_\alpha:=\{x \in E : f(x) > \alpha \}.$$
Prove then that
$$m(E_\alpha) \le \frac{1}{\alpha} \int_E f dm. $$

Here is my attempt:

First we define the simple function
$$g(x)=\alpha \chi_{E_\alpha}(x).$$
As $f$ is defined on all of $E$ where as $g$ is defined over $E_\alpha$ together with zero product property we have that
$$0 \le g(x) \le f(x).$$
Thus by monotonicity of the Lebesgue integral we have that
\begin{align*}
     \alpha m(E_\alpha) &= \int_{E_\alpha} g(x) dm \\
     &\le \int_E f(x) dm
 \end{align*}
And as $\alpha$ is non-zero we can divide by it and we get the desired result.

Furthermore, assuming $\int_E f=0$ we can use the inequality to show $f=0$ a.e. on $E$. Take $\alpha = \frac{1}{n}$ for some (this is some $n$ correct??) $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Next compute the measure of $E_{\frac{1}{n}}$ using the inequality. \begin{align*}
     m(E_{\frac{1}{n}}) &\le \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}} \int_E f dm \\
     &= n \int_E f dm \\ 
     &= n (0) \\
     &=0
 \end{align*}
Thus $m(E_{\frac{1}{n}})=0.$ Before we continue note that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E_{\frac{1}{n}}=E_0$. And we can compute
\begin{align*}
     m(E_0) &= m(\{x \in E : f(x) >0\}) \\ 
     &= m (\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{x \in E : f(x) > \frac{1}{n}\}),
 \end{align*}
which is a countable union of measure zero sets thus by countable sub-additivity we have that $m(E_0)=0$. I get stuck showing that $m(E_0)=0$ gives me $m(E)=0$ and thus $f$ is identically zero a.e. on $E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want $m(E) = 0$ (it's not true in any interesting case).

For $f$ non-negative, $E_0 = \{x \in E : f(x) \neq 0\}$, so $m(E_0) = 0$ is precisely $f=0$ a.e.

Comment: ah you're right I don't know why I did not catch that! Because $\frac{1}{n}$ goes to $0$!